# There's a relation between King Turret and Portal 2 story?

Tags: portal-2

When you start playing a new chamber in story mode, in these big screens in the elevator sometime shows a big turret called "King turret".

Who's and what is he doing there?
Maybe the surface was invaded by the King Turret?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Animal King Turret](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Animal_King_Turret) is first seen during Chapter 1 ("Courtesy Call") on the screen in the elevator room just before test chamber 2. As the player exits the elevator, the recorded announcer gives the following voice-over:

> If the Earth is currently governed by a manner of animal-king, sentient cloud, or other governing body that either refuses to or is incapable of listening to reason, th--[RECORDING CUTS OUT]

[Video source](https://youtu.be/3G4MoZ51iiI?t=550)

The turret is just a comical representation of a ruler unwilling or incapable of listening to reason. There's nothing in-game which suggests that the above-ground has been taken over by a gigantic turret.

Comment: Or course not... the surface has been taken over by the [Combine](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Combine) instead.

Comment: The recording says "sentient cloud", although "sentient butt" is funnier.

Comment: @Gieron I copy-pasted from the wiki and forgot I had the cloud-to-butt extension installed--or rather, I thought I had submitted it correctly and it was being swapped after the fact. =P Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score -3):

the animal king turret was originally part of a scrapped plot thread where Chell helps out a tribe of lost turrets and the animal king turret marries one of the turrets to Chell. the turret bride woould then follow Chell for the rest of the game.